# Display text one after the other in Javascript - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am currently receiving Push notifications. Here is my part of my JS.

Instead of Alerts (pop ups), I want to display the messages one after the other.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

I tried creating a div and going with this instead. It doesn't work.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {

  document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = (data.message);​

});
```

And this is my DIV.

```
<div id="MyEdit"> </div>
```

I also tried this:

```
 var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
document.write(data.message);
}

});
```

Still nothing is showing up. Alerts work. Writes don't.

Comment: Have you tried it with the alert and the innerHTML write?

Comment: Try : document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = data.message;
Without the ( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML += data.message;​
```

If you use jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('#MyEdit').append(data.message);
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with firebug? Use console.log(data.message), maybe the message is empty

Comment: how do I add a new line for new entries? - $('#MyEdit').append(data.message);

Comment: You can wrap data.message into a div $('#MyEdit').append('<div>' + data.message + '</div>');or you can simply add a <br/> after each message $('#MyEdit').append(data.message + '<br/>');

Answer (score 1):

Below code will make for jQuery append method. Simply instead of adding next text to innnerHtml, add new div elements, it will help to wrap them with some css, add some padding etc.

```
var messageRow = document.createElement("div");
var textNode = document.createTextNode(data.message);
messageRow.appendChild(textNode);
document.appendChild(messageRow);
```